# Render Layers and Freestyle

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-layers, freestyle

I am trying to make an animation where everything but the hair and eyelashes is "Freestyled." I have two different Render Layers:

1. Freestyle
2. No Freestyle

I have successfully made the "No Freestyle" layer completely void of Freestyling. However, for some reason everything behind the hair-and-eyelash-alpha-textured-objects is rendered as complete transparency, making the eyes look weird.

Is there a way to fix this?

Alternatively, is there another way to stop the hair and eyelashes from being effected by freestyle?

[image]